# Python/Flask: only one user can call a endpoint at one time

Tags: python, flask

I have a API build using Python/Flask, and I have a endpoint called `/build-task` that called by the system, and this endpoint takes about 30 minutes to run.

My question is that how do I lock the `/build-task` endpoint when it's started and running already? So so other user, or system CANNOT call this endpoint.

Comment: Just use a flag that is reset every 30 minutes

Comment: But what if it takes 40 minutes, or just 20? Hardcoding a time for something to run is a bit dubious. Just use a flag which changes when it's started/done, or check the db as mentioned in Marcelo's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to save the data into the database and check it before running the endpoint function.

Here's also another quick'n'dirty approach using Flask's 'app' to store the time:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'Wow a Secret!'


@app.route('/build-task')
def build_task():
    print ()
    if datetime.now() - app.task_start_time > timedelta(seconds=10):
        app.task_start_time = datetime.now()
        return "I am running a great task now :)"
    else:
        return "Cannot help you!<br>You will have to wait until we reach 10 seconds: " + str(datetime.now() - app.task_start_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.task_start_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=10)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some approaches for this problem:

1 - You can create a session object, save a flag in the object and check if the endpoint is already running and respond accordingly.

2 - Flag on the database, check if the endpoint is already running and respond accordingly.